# Why does creating new resource error with NameError (uninitialized constant Thing::user)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, activerecord

In a Rails 5.1 project I've got resources: "Thing" (we'll call it) and "User", and I'm ajaxing a POST from users#show view to "/thing" to create a new Thing.

things_controller.rb

```
def create
  @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @thing.save
      format.json { render json: @thing }
```

where `thing_params` is `params.require(:thing).permit(:name, :owner_id)`

On `@thing.save` I get this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Thing::user):

app/controllers/things_controller.rb:54:in `block in create'
app/controllers/things_controller.rb:53:in `create'
::1 - - [22/Feb/2018:11:19:36 PST] "POST /things HTTP/1.1" 500 168176
http://localhost:3000/users/1 -> /things
```

If I `p params` I get

> Parameters: {"name"=>"Hatrack", "owner_id"=>1,
>   "thing"=>{"name"=>"Hatrack", "owner_id"=>1}}

I understand cross-controller requests are discouraged in favor of setting up routes in a fixed way for this, but I'd like these two resources not to be nested. Here are my routes for these:

```
resources :users

resources :things do
  resources :photos
end
```

That last line in the error `localhost:3000/users/1 -> /things` makes me think the things controller is looking for a related resource 'Thing::user' because of the request source? How can I make this happy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to define your association with a class. 
`belongs to user, class: "User"`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Forgot to add my model info:
    ```class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :owner, class_name: :user```
slightly different syntax, but I migrated from Rails 4 - think this is still valid

Comment: That was it!
`class_name: "User"` did the trick. @David Weber I didn't try `class:`, so that may work too. ActiveRecord docs are saying to use `class_name`. But yes I mistook the syntactic sugar to create an alias for the foreign key ("User" turns to `user_id`) for a symbol pointing to the User model. If I understand that right(?) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I mean class_name that is my fault. And yes that is right you needed to specific the class name. You will run into this anytime you see *Name of class you are calling from*::*Name of class you meant*